# Prove that 1/n+1/(n+1)+...+(1/2n)>=1/2

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-verification

Prove that $\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{n+1}+...+\frac{1}{2n}\geq\frac{1}{2}$.

I proceed by induction on $n$. For $n=1$, the inequality is obvious. 
Then, assuming $\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{n+1}+...+\frac{1}{2n}\geq\frac{1}{2}$ (our induction hypothesis), let's prove $\frac{1}{n+1}+...+\frac{1}{2n}+\frac{1}{2n+2}\geq\frac{1}{2}$. We notice that left sides are the same except for the fraction $\frac{1}{n}$ (present only in the hypothesis) and $\frac{1}{2n+2}$ (present only in the statement we want to prove. We could have $\frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{n+2}+...+\frac{1}{2n}=x$, then knowing that $\frac{1}{n}+x\geq\frac{1}{2}$ we would have to prove that $\frac{1}{2n+2}+x\geq\frac{1}{2}$.

I think that induction is a good way of proving the given inequality but cannot proceed with the proof (any errors on the way?) so I'd appreciate a hint.

Comment: Your induction step is missing the term $1/(2n+1)$.

Comment: Why $1/(2n+1)$ should be there? We are considering the sum of fractions up to $1/(2n)$.

Comment: Yes exactly, and the integer right before $2(n+1)$ is $2n + 1$. In particular, where you wrote $\cdots + \frac{1}{2n} + \frac{1}{2n+2}$ that should be $\cdots + \frac{1}{2n} + \frac{1}{2n+1} + \frac{1}{2n+2}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\frac1n+\frac1{n+1}+\dots+\frac1{2n}$ is the sum of $n+1$ terms, each of which is greater than or equal to $\frac1{2n}$.  So the sum is greater than or equal to $(n+1)\frac1{2n}$, which is greater than $\frac12$.

Answer (score 0):

Try subtracting the left side of your inductive step from the left side of the hypothesis and work from there.